# Why CPU utilization of CMS garbage collector is lower than Throughput garbage collector in this case

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Generally speaking the CPU utilization of CMS garbage collector (or any other concurrent garbage collector) is higher than the throughput garbage collector and it's mentioned in the book Java performance The definitive guide on page 108:

> When using the CMS or G1 collector, an application will typically
> experience fewer (and much shorter) pauses. The trade-off is that the
> application will use more CPU overall.

And on page 109:

> The benefit of avoiding long pause times with a concurrent collector
> comes at the expense of extra CPU usage.

But there is an example in the book on page 115 in which CMS collector has lower CPU utilization(both average and pick):

> The throughput collector will (by default) consume 100% of the CPU
> available on the machine while it runs, so a more accurate
> representation of the CPU usage during this test is shown in Figure
> 5-2. Most of the time, only the application thread is running,
> consuming 25% of the total CPU. When GC kicks in, 100% of the CPU is
> consumed. Hence, the actual CPU usage resembles the sawtooth pattern
> in the graph, even though the average during the test is reported as
> the value of the straight dashed line.
>
> [image]
>
> The effect is different in a concurrent collector, when there are
> background thread(s) running concurrently with the application
> threads. In that case, a graph of the CPU might look like Figure 5-3.
>
> [image]
>
> The application thread starts by using 25% of the total CPU.
> Eventually it has created enough garbage for the CMS background thread
> to kick in; that thread also consumes an entire CPU, bringing the
> total up to 50%. When the CMS thread finishes, CPU usage drops to 25%,
> and so on. Note that there are no 100% peak-CPU periods, which is a
> little bit of a simplification: there will be very short spikes to
> 100% CPU usage during the CMS young generation collections, but those
> are short enough that we can ignore them for this discussion.

Why in this case CMS garbage collector could have lower CPU usage than Throughput garbage collector?

Comment: 1) these are completely made-up graphs with no connection to reality. 2) The CPU utilization doesn’t tell you when you will finish your actual job. Better throughput means, you might finish your job after one minute instead of two or process ten incoming requests in a second instead of only five.

Comment: Although the author claims that this result came from a real test, I agree that there should be something wrong or misprint here, However, CPU utilization is nearly as important as throughput in Java garbage collection world, because it directly affect throughput, when there is no CPU cycle available for background thread, collector should do full GC which is very expensive.

Comment: That’s not how it works. The CPU utilization does not influence the decision to do a Full GC or not. Neither does it have much real life relevance to assume that an application will continuously use 25% CPU. And regarding the “real test result”, math says, to get a spike in a “30-second-average” graph that reaches the 100%, you need a 100% CPU utilization for 30 seconds. That’s an impressively high amount of GC work…

Comment: @Holger I thought that it was the only mistake in the book but now you are saying that this claim from the book is also wrong: If extra CPU is available (and that might be a big if), then using a concurrent collector
will give the application a nice performance boost. The key here is whether adequate
CPU is available for the background processing of the concurrent GC threads

Comment: It’s not entirely wrong. It’s possible to have a concurrent garbage collection thread running on one CPU core and an application thread running on another. But think about it this way: when the true fraction of the garbage collection makes 1% of your application’s CPU time (which is not an unreasonable number) would you really consider keeping a CPU core free for the GC for the whole time? Or rather, let the application use the CPU as much as it can and let the 1% come naturally, as you never manage to consume the CPU 100% the entire time?

Comment: @Holger I completely agree with you in that point, I did not mean that we should not use CPU cycle and save them for garbage collector.  The point that I was trying to make was that we should run the application and monitor its CPU usage, if its CPU usage is too high and there is no CPU cycle available for concurrent garbage collector we should not go for concurrent garbage collector, otherwise using concurrent garbage collector can be a choice depending on other requirements. Is that correct?(although in java 9+ default collector is G1)?

Comment: The available cycles would need to be less than the actual overhead of the concurrent garbage collector, compared to the hypothetical parallel GC that you would use instead. Further, “max throughput” needs to be your primary goal, rather than, e.g. “limit max pause time”. Another problem is, all modern GCs are concurrent, so all improvements go there; the parallel GC is just there for compatibility. Certain features, like string deduplication, may outweigh the other effects, so you may end up at using one of the modern concurrent collectors anyway.

Comment: @Holger Thanks Holger, that was great!

Comment: @Holger imo you should craft this as an answer.